# How can I include the logo in some slides and remove in others, using beamer?

Tags: beamer

I want to include a logo in my slides. I am using this:

```
\logo{\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{../../Logos/CMS_logo_black.png}}
```

but, due to some graphics are big, in some slides the main graphic overlays the logo.

How can I remove the logo from some slides but keep it in others?

Thanks,

Comment: `\begin{frame}[plain]` could be a solution.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There are two simple ways to do this:

### With a conditional

You can create a conditional to insert the logo only if the condition is true, and then turn the logo on and off as needed.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newif\ifplacelogo % create a new conditional
\placelogotrue % set it to true
\logo{\ifplacelogo\color{red}\rule{.5cm}{.5cm}\fi} % replace with your own command
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
   \frametitle{Test frame}
\end{frame}
\placelogofalse % turn the logo off (needs to be outside the {frame} environment)
\begin{frame}
   \frametitle{Test frame no logo}
\end{frame}
\placelogotrue % turn the logo back on for subsequent slides
\begin{frame}
   \frametitle{Test frame with logo again}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### With grouping and local redefinition

Another alternative, which doesn't require a conditional, would be to enclose the frame (or set of frames) in a group and redefine the logo template within the group.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\logo{\color{red}\rule{.5cm}{.5cm}}
\newcommand{\nologo}{\setbeamertemplate{logo}{}} % command to set the logo to nothing
\title{A title}
\author{An author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}[t]\frametitle{Test frame}
\end{frame}

% must enclose the frame(s) without the logo in braces
% any number of frames can be within the group (here 2).

{\nologo
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Test frame no logo}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Another Test frame no logo}
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{Test frame with logo again}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

I was fighting to do the same on specific slides belonging to the same frame. 
My problem was that image was overlapping with the logo and navigation bars after zooming.

I figured it out extending the above solution by Alan and decided to share in case someone has the same problem:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{A title}
\author{An author}
\logo{\includegraphics[height=0.8cm]{logo.pdf}}

\newcommand{\nologo}{\setbeamertemplate{logo}{}} % command to set the logo to nothing
\newcommand{\nonavi}{\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}} % command to set the navigation symbols to nothing

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

% show only the first slide of the frame with logo and navigation symbols present, give a label
\frame<1>[label=myframe]
{
  \frametitle{My frame}
  \framezoom<1><2>(0cm,0cm)(8cm,4cm)
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{some_picture.pdf}
}

% bring back the frame using \againframe enclosed in braces with \nologo\nonavi
{\nologo\nonavi
\againframe<2>{myframe}
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done better with the code of the style file.

https://github.com/martinhelso/UiB

On this link you can find that this code

```
\hidelogo
\begin{frame}
...
\end{frame}
```

removes the logo

Use \showlogo in the same manner to make the logo appear again.