# prevent logo from title page in beamer class

Tags: beamer, positioning

I'm having problems with inserting a logo on my presentation in the beamer class.

```
\logo{\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{logo.png}}
```

This is how I inserted the logo, which works perfectly; it is placed in the lower right hand corner as desired.

But I don't want the logo on the title slide. Is there a way to hide the logo on the title slide?

Comment: You should also upvote Alan Munn's answer (this has to be done separately from accepting).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use

```
\frame[plain]{\titlepage}
```

instead of `\maketitle` to make your titlepage slide.

Depending on your needs, the following question might also be of use:

[How can I include the logo in some slides and remove in others, using beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53781/2693).

Comment: Wow, that was fast and very helpful! Thanks also for the link.

Answer (score 10):

Another option, which only removes the logo but maintains all the other elements, is to locally redefine the `logo` template for the title page:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}

\logo{\includegraphics[scale=0.02]{ctanlion}}

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}
\institute{The Institute}

\begin{document}

{
\setbeamertemplate{logo}{}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

CTAN lion drawing by Duane Bibby.

Comment: Thanks for this as well. Still amazing how many things are possible with Latex....

Comment: Just don't forget to remove `ignorenonframetext` option from beamer class; this had me stumped for quite a while...

Answer (score 4):

A simpler solution is to define the logo immediately after the `titlepage` such that it doesn't appear in that frame.

For example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}
\institute{The Institute}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

% insert the logo here
\logo{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{logopolito}} % <= test image 
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

will produce the following frames:

[image]

[image]

Of course, the method holds for all subsequent frames in your presentation.

Comment: The easy solution I was looking for.