# How can I reposition the logo in some slides?

Tags: beamer

On my slides, I include a logo as follows:

```tex
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
    \begin{textblock*}{100mm}(9.55cm, -0.50cm){
            \includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image}}
    \end{textblock*}
}
```

This has worked very well for me so far. However, on some slides it is necessary to reposition the logo. [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53781/how-can-i-include-the-logo-in-some-slides-and-remove-in-others-using-beamer/) asks on how to remove the logo on some slides and keep it on others, but is there a possibility readjust the logo on some slides?

Here's an MWE:

```tex
\documentclass[10pt, aspectratio=43]{beamer}
\usepackage{textpos}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
    \begin{textblock*}{100mm}(9.55cm, -0.50cm){
            \includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image}}
    \end{textblock*}
}
\begin{document}
    % Use grouping to adjust the logo on some slides. 
    {
    % \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{}
    \addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
        \begin{textblock*}{100mm}(9.55cm, -1.05cm){
                \includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image}}
        \end{textblock*}
    }
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Test Slide 1}
        Test
    \end{frame}
    }
    
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Test Slide 2}
        Test 
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this leads to *two* logos on the first slide. And if I comment out

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{}
```

then there is no frametitle and no logo at all.

Can anybody help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the y position of the textblock as a macro, and then redefine that macro:

```
\documentclass[10pt, aspectratio=43]{beamer}
\usepackage{textpos}
\def\ypos{-0.50cm}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
    \begin{textblock*}{100mm}(9.55cm, \ypos){
            \includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image}}
    \end{textblock*}
}
\begin{document}
    % Use grouping to adjust the logo on some slides. 
    {
    \def\ypos{-1.05cm}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Test Slide 1}
        Test
    \end{frame}
    }
    
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Test Slide 2}
        Test 
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]